# Passing user input to fopen() parameter c

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to get a user to input a path to a file. I will then take this file and open it with fopen(). Here is an example of what I am currently trying:

```
char filename[80] = " ";
printf("enter filenme:");
scanf("%s",&filename);
FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"r");
```

I keep getting segmentation fault:11 as an error from the terminal.

Comment: Did you debug? What's the value of `filename` after `scanf` is called? You should use `char filename[80] = {0};`. Are you sure 80 chars are enough, though?

Comment: Are you _sure_ passing a pointer to `filename` is correct when using `scanf`?

Comment: Strictly, you should pass `filename` and not `&filename` to `scanf()` as the latter has the type `char (*)[80]` which is not the same as `char *` that `%s` expects.  However, the value passed ends up being the same, so you should get compiler warnings (or you should get a better compiler).  What do you enter as the file name?

Comment: I don't know why people down vote, it's not a bad question.. Just a mistake we all made at one point in learning the language. Also this is valid in C++ if you include the cstdio header, but it is definitely of the C style. If fixed up it would compile under g++ and gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this C++, you should consider using [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) to read the filename:

```
string filename;
std::cout << "Enter filename: ";
std::getline(std::cin, filename);
std::ifstream input_file(filename, std::ifstream::in);
// ... read from input_file ....
```

If you are going to read the filename into a fixed size buffer, make sure that you specify that length of the buffer when reading; otherwise, you have a buffer overflow vulnerability in your program.

Comment: Agreed that since the question is tagged C++, the use of the C standard I/O library is inappropriate, in general.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the address of the address of the start of filename. Don't use the &. It's an array, so it's already a pointer to the address that is stored.

Comment: You're correct that what is being passed should not be prefixed with the `&`.  However, it isn't really clear what you mean by "the address of the address of the start of `filename`".  It is the address of the array, type `char (*)[80]` which certainly does not match the type `char *` expected by `scanf()`, but it is not really 'the address of the address'.  Numerically, it has the same value as `&filename[0]` and `filename`, but the type is different.

Comment: Basically calling: char filename[80]; you are create a character array (char*) that is preallocated to hold 80 char. So even though it doesn't explicitly say char* the [80] is creating the char*. Not sure If I explained that clearly. But, he doesn't need to set it equal to " ", he would be fine without that.

Comment: Look at the example here: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

it uses the exact same method

Answer (score 1):

Although the argument passed to `scanf()` isn't quite right, I don't think this is actually the problem: the address of the array and the address of the first character of the array are the same. Much more likely `fopen()` fails and you get a null-pointer from `fopen()` which you then access. That is, try something like this:

```
char filename[80] = {};
if (scanf("%79s", filename) != 1) {
    printf("failed to read a filename\n");
}
else if (FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r")) {
    printf("reading file '%s'\n", filename);
}
else {
    printf("failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", filename);
}
```

(based on the comments it seems `"%79s"` is the proper format to limit reading too many characters into an array of 80 characters but I'm not a C programmer, i.e., I may have messed up the proper format...)

The equivalent using C++ would be this which is probably preferable:

```
std::string filename;
if (!(std::cin >> filename)) {
    std::cout << "failed to read a filename\n";
}
else if (std::ifstream in{filename}) {
    std::cout << "reading file '" << filename << "'\n";
}
else {
    std::cout << "failed to open file '" << filename << "' for reading\n";
}
```

Comment: FYI: `%79s` is correct; the Standard I/O library was created before the general idiom of 'include the terminal null in the length' was standard.  It is more like `strlen()`, therefore.  Also, I don't think you can define `FILE *fp` in the `else if` statement like that.  However, the basic diagnosis is plausible; a likely cause of trouble is that the file is not opened.

Comment: I think you need "%79[^\n]s" so that you leave one character for the '\0' and you skip the newline (but also not 100% sure... I typically avoid scanf because it is super dangerous to use).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get an error: your are passing the **address** of a pointer to `scanf` instead of the pointer itself:

```
scanf("%s",&filename);
```

Change it to

```
scanf("%s", filename);
```

or

```
scanf("%s",&(filename[0]));
```

and your problems should be gone.

Comment: No; the code passes the address of the array (and an array is _not_ a pointer).  You're right there is a type mismatch; you are wrong about the value and consequences.

Comment: This isn't indicating the length of the buffer and is therefore still a buffer overflow vulnerability.

Comment: sorry for being imprecise, you are right - &(filename[0]) is the pointer - the name of array is a programming language construct, of course